# JQuery: How to return Form output number?

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Hi everyone this is my first time using this site please bear with me because I have no experience in javascript coding.
I have the following in my javascript file:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("input").click(function(event) {
    updateTotal();

});
});

function updateTotal() {
var total = 13600;
$("#menu input:checked").each(function() {
    total += parseFloat(this.value);
});
$('#TotalCost').val("$" + total.toFixed(2));
}
```

**And in my source code I have:**

```
            <div class= "checkbox" style="margin-top: 20px" id= "menu">

                Cost of Dinner
                <p>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="-200.00" name="Hamburger">Hamburger ($2)<br/>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="-400" name="French Fries">French Fries ($1)<br/>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="-1.5" name="Shake">Shake ($3)<br/> 
                </p>

            <p>
                Total Cost: <input type="text" name="TotlCost" id="TotalCost"     size="10"/>
            </p>

<div>
```

**How do I format so the updateTotal() will return a number that has commas?
I found this code online that formats a string with commas**

```
function commas(str) {
    return str.replace(/.(?=(?:.{3})+$)/g, '$&,');
}
```

**How do I use it? 
Thank you very much for your help.**

Answer (score 0):

Try adding that function to your JavaScript file and then changing your code to something like:

```
function updateTotal() {
    var total = 13600;
    $("#menu input:checked").each(function() {
        total += parseFloat(this.value);
    });
    var val = commas(total.toFixed(2).toString());
    $('#TotalCost').val("$" + val);
 }
```

This sets `val` to the total with commas.

Comment: Hi David, thank you very much for your help. It worked. Except the function commas was broken. I ended up getting $13,000,.00. I did find a new function that works. I will show my new solution in a following reply incase if someone needs it.

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
    $("input").click(function(event) {
        updateTotal();

    });
    });

    function updateTotal() {
    var total = 13600;
    $("#menu input:checked").each(function() {
        total += parseFloat(this.value);
    });
    var val = addCommas(total.toFixed(2).toString());
    $('#TotalCost').val("$" + val);

    }

Comment: function addCommas(nStr) {
    nStr += '';
    x = nStr.split('.');
    x1 = x[0];
    x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
    var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
    while (rgx.test(x1)) {
        x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
    }
    return x1 + x2;
    }